# Alexa utterances - variable lengths

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I need to create an utterance where the user needs to say either a 4, 5 or 6 character code. Each code is alphanumeric.

How do I design the utterance so that a variable length code can be used?

For the six-digit code, I have the following:

```
MySkill look up code {XXX_ONE} {XXX_TWO} {XXX_THREE} {XXX_FOUR} {XXX_FIVE} {XXX_SIX}
```

where the slots are defined as :

```
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "XXX_ONE",
      "type": "ALPHANUM"
    },
    {
      "name": "XXX_TWO",
      "type": "ALPHANUM"
    },
    {
      "name": "XXX_THREE",
      "type": "ALPHANUM"
    },
    {
      "name": "XXX_FOUR",
      "type": "ALPHANUM"
    },
    {
      "name": "XXX_FIVE",
      "type": "ALPHANUM"
    },
    {
      "name": "XXX_SIX",
      "type": "ALPHANUM"
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

this is really similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397892/alexa-skill-user-input-for-spelling-out-letters) and also similar to the intent ADDWORD in [this repo](https://github.com/skezo/spell-master) 
The main idea is you can create a custom slot type, let say `CODE`, and it can have the values like `a.b.c.1.2.3` for code `ABC123` and so on for your all your multiple codes independently of the length.

In this case the utterance will not be accepted if spelling a non existing code, if you want to accept those you could add as values all the possible combinations of alphanumeric characters with 4, 5 and 6.

> It isn't very well documented, but you can use "a.", "b.", "c." etc to
>   represent the letter, as opposed to the sound.