# Amazon Lex - receive spoken spelled out word, what slot type should I use?

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

**Goal**

User should spell out their name one letter at a time, for example: "s a r a h" / "ess ay are ay aych".

Lex should understand and convert it to text together: "sarah"

**What I've tried**

I'm using Amazon Connect (IVR/phone, user speaks into the phone to spell their name) which is using Lex to listen and convert to text.

I've tried a "AlphaNumeric" slot but it rarely works. I've also tried custom slots for all letters e.g. "a.", "b." - also rarely works.

Has anyone dealt with this? Any direction/experience would be appreciated re. handling **spoken** **(not typed/chat bot)** letter-by-letter input using Lex and preferably also Connect.

**Other research I've done**

https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/9331/letter-of-the-alphabet-slot-type.html - this author apparently took the custom letter slot approach, but doesn't really confirm if it worked overall. I've tried this and it's not working, but maybe I'm missing something important.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=261741 - AWS support thread which isn't very helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you click the **+** next to *Slot types* you'll have the option to *Extend slot type*. If you click this you can create a new slot type with a regular expression based on your use case. For a first name that might be `[a-z]{2,25}`. I think the max length for these is 30, so `[a-z]{1,40}` would fail.